# Show loading icon in the activity titlebar

Tags: android, user-interface

How do you show a loading icon in the activity titlebar?

Comment: did you mean a ProgressBar indeterminate in the title bar? or a custom icon in the title bar?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
}
```

Then... where ever you want:

```
// then, you can do this to show the icon
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
//or to hide it
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Make sure to use `requestWindowFeature` before `setContentView`.

Comment: doesn't do anything (i did exactly what you specified..)

Comment: These are the kind of jewels you expect to find on SO. Thanks ;-).