# Android loading icon in title bar across multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399845/show-loading-icon-in-the-activity-titlebar) post to put a loading icon in the title bar of my Android App:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    }
```

The code:

```
  activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

is called in an AsyncTask.  If the user navigates to a new activity, the icon is not longer present in the title bar since the icon was set for the first activity only.

Is there a way to have the icon show on all activities?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create super activity (i.e. Base Activity), include the below line in this super activity:

```
 activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

And extends this activity to all the child activities.

Comment: Additional suggestion: Instead of using built-in title bar, you can define your own title bar or ActionBar. Try it out. It will make your app looking good.